# Solve through iteration $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$

Tags: recursion, recursive-algorithms

My problem with this is the final step. Through iterative substitution, I come up with the following:
$$T(n) = T(n-4) + (n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n$$

which leads to the general form:
$$T(n) = T(n-k) + kn - \frac{[k(k-1)]}{2}$$

The restrictions are $T(1)=1$ and $n=2^k-1$. What I am doing at this point is solving for $k$, when $T(1) = 1$ which gives me :
$$n = 2^k - 1$$
$$n + 1 = 2^k$$
$$2 = 2^k$$
($n=1$, since this is for $T(1)=1$)

$$1 = k$$

plugging back in I just come up with the original formula which is obviously not correct.

What am I doing wrong in the final step (if that really is my problem)? Based on other examples I have seen, this would work out nicely if I can put $k$ in terms of $n$ instead of a constant, but I am drawing a blank on how to do this and I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, one may use a *telescoping sum*. From
$$
T(k)-T(k-1)=k, \qquad k=1,2,3,\cdots, \tag1
$$ one gets
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(T(k)-T(k-1)\right)=T(n)-T(0)=\sum_{k=1}^n k, \qquad n\ge1,
$$ giving

> $$
> T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}2+T(0),\qquad n\ge1.
> $$

Comment: wouldn't T(0) be undefined since n>=1?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}T(n)&=T(n-1)+n\\T(n)&=T(n-2)+(n-1)+n\\T(n)&=T(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n\\ &\vdots\\T(n)&=T(n-k)+(n-k+1)+(n-k+2)+\cdots+n\\ &\vdots\\T(n)&=T(1)+2+3+\cdots+n\\T(n)&=1+2+3+\cdots+n\\T(n)&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: I guess this is my problem.  I don't see how you get to that point from my solution or just in general.

I get that T(1) = 1 but where does T(n) = T(1)+2+3+⋯+n come from?  

Where did the k number of n's go to?

Comment: sorry, i am having trouble formatting this so it is clearly readable and I have to take my daughter to school, so I am rushing a little bit.

Comment: @thePetester As $T(1)$ is the base, you would expand $n$ times. The $T(n-k)$ stage is an intermediate stage, but eventually, you will reach $T(1)$ after which you can directly substitute the value. But you seem to be using two different definitions of $k$, which seems to be confusing

Comment: Hi GoodDeeds, your explanation has cleared it up for me.  I was definitely confusing the k terms in each part of the problem.  As soon as I used a different variable, it became much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{rcl}T(n) &=& T(n-1) + n \\
&=& T(n-2) + (n-1) + n \\
&=& \ldots \\
&=& T(n-[n-1]) + (n-[n-2]) + (n-[n-3]) + \ldots + n \\
&=& T(1) + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n \\
&=& 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots \\
&=& \sum_{j=1}^{n}j \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)
\end{array}$

If $n = 2^{k}-1$ then $T(n) = T(2^{k}-1) = \frac{1}{2}(2^{k}-1)(2^{k}-1+1) = (2^{k}-1)2^{k-1}$